# pandas calculate variance from aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, variance

I have a data frame with these columns: `Date`, `ID`, and `Value`. And I need to perform mean, median and variance on `Value` and I used `.agg` like this:

```
df = dataset\
    .groupby(['ID', pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='60T')])['Value']\
    .agg(['mean', 'median', 'var'])\
    .reset_index()
```

It successfully calculates mean, but when it need to calculate median it simply repeats the mean value and doesn't store or create the var column. Here's the result:

```
      ID                 Date      mean    median  var
0  13834  2017-02-09 12:00:00  1.474920  1.474920  NaN
1  13834  2017-02-09 16:00:00  4.424796  4.424796  NaN
2  13834  2017-02-09 20:00:00  2.241871  2.241871  NaN
3  13834  2017-02-10 00:00:00  2.654867  2.654867  NaN
4  13834  2017-02-10 04:00:00  2.654867  2.654867  NaN
5  13834  2017-02-10 08:00:00  0.511062  0.511062  NaN
```

At the end of the last number there should be the variance column, instead I get nothing (or `NaN`s, if shown in a data frame). How do I fix this?

Comment: Just theoretically - maybe your grouping returns one row per group - then naturally mean=median and var=0 ?

Comment: for mean = median it can be, but why var remains nan and not 0?

Comment: Because you have 1 row per group - check in a dummy example: ``` df.groupby(df.index).agg(["mean", "median", "var"]).reset_index()``` - it apparently uses variance estimator with 1/(N-1), which returns NaN, if N=1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance

Comment: omg, you're right. So I simply fillna(0). Thank you!

Comment: No worries, glad it worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Grzegorz Skibinski's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842316/pandas-calculate-variance-from-aggregation#comment102112311_57842316) is the solution:

> Because you have 1 row per group - check in a dummy example:  `df.groupby(df.index).agg(["mean", "median", "var"]).reset_index()` - it apparently uses variance estimator with 1/(N-1), which returns NaN, if N=1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance